# Random sample of paired lists in Python

Tags: python, random

I have two lists *x* and *y*, both of length *n*, with *x<sub>i</sub>* and *y<sub>i</sub>* forming a pair. How could I take a random sample of *m* values from these two lists while preserving the pairing information (e.g. x[10] and y[10] would be together in the resulting sample)

My initial idea is this.

- use zip to create a list of tuples
- shuffle the list of tuples
- select the first *m* tuples from the list
- break up the tuples into new paired lists

And the code would look something like this.

```
templist = list()
for tup in zip(x, y):
    templist.append(tup)
random.shuffle(templist)
x_sub = [a for a, b in templist[0:m]]
y_sub = [b for a, b in templist[0:m]]
```

This seems rather kludgy to me. Is there any way I could make this more clear, concise, or Pythonic?

Comment: Have you looked at [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)?

Comment: @metatoaster As a replacement for the shuffle command? The whole solution would still be a bit kludgy. Unless `random.sample` could take two paired lists as input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can sample m pairs and split those into two lists with the following code:

```
import random

x = list(range(1, 10))
y = list("abcdefghij")
m = 3

x_sub, y_sub = zip(*random.sample(list(zip(x, y)), m))
```

Comment: I like that this solution creates two new lists, rather than a single list of tuples. Kind of dense otherwise, but conciseness and clarity always seem to be at odds!

Comment: I get an error trying to execute this (assuming m=3)

Comment: @Alexander `m` is the sample size, the OP didn't provide it just the variable `m`, what error - works fine for me.

Comment: @Alexander sampling m elements in the two lists

Comment: With the following inputs, I get the following error (Python 2.7.10): x = [1,2,3,4,5]

y = [6,7,8,9,10]

m = 3  TypeError: random_sample() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)

Comment: @Alexander what is `random_sample()`? please `import random` then do `random.sample()`

Comment: @JerryDay Yes, that works. I was using `np.random.sample` Thx for clarifying the module.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two lists with elements that are direct pairs of each other and simply `zip` them (and in python 3, cast that object into a `list`), then use `random.sample` to take a sample.

```
>>> m = 4
>>> x = list(range(0, 3000, 3))
>>> y = list(range(0, 2000, 2))
>>> random.sample(list(zip(x, y)), m)
[(2145, 1430), (2961, 1974), (9, 6), (1767, 1178)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have two lists of the same dimensions, you just want to sample a subset of these elements and pair the results.

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5] 
y = [6,7,8,9,10]
sample_size = 3
idx = np.random.choice(len(x), size=sample_size, replace=False)
pairs = [(x[n], y[n]) for n in idx]
>>> pairs
[(5, 10), (2, 7), (1, 6)]
```

Comment: when I ran the code, it shows "SyntaxError: closing parenthesis ')' does not match opening parenthesis '['. I've tried to adjust it but not successful. Can you have a look, please?

Comment: @MarkK Corrected above.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `random_product` itertools recipe.  I will use a third-party library, [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools), that implements this recipe for us.  Install this library via `pip install more_itertools`.

**Code**

```
import more_itertool as mit


x, y, m = "abcdefgh", range(10), 2

iterable = mit.random_product(x, y, repeat=m)
```

**Results**

```
iterable
# ('e', 9, 'f', 3)
```

It is not clear in what form the OP wants the results, but you can group `x` and `y` together, e.g. `[(x[0], y[0]), (x[1], y[1]), ...]`:

```
paired_xy = list(zip(*[iter(iterable)]*2))
paired_xy
# [('e', 9), ('f', 3)]
```

See also [`more_itertools.sliced`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.sliced) and [`more_itertools.grouper`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.grouper) for grouping consecutive items.

Alternatively, you may `zip` further to group along `x` and `y`, e.g.  `[(x[0], x[1], ...), (y[0], y[1], ...)]`:

```
paired_xx = list(zip(*paired_xy))
paired_xx
# [('e', 'f'), (9, 3)]
```

Note, this approach accepts any number of iterables, `x`, `y`, `z`, etc.

```
# Select m random items from multiples iterables, REF 101
x, y, m = "abcdefgh", range(10), 2
a, b, c = "ABCDE", range(10, 100, 10), [False, True]
iterable = mit.random_product(x, y, a, b, c, repeat=m) 
iterable
# ('d', 6, 'E', 80, True, 'a', 1, 'D', 50, False)
```

---

**Details**

From the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
def random_product(*args, repeat=1):
    "Random selection from itertools.product(*args, **kwds)"
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    return tuple(random.choice(pool) for pool in pools)
```

We can see the function indeed accepts multiple arguments which each become a collection of pools.  The size of the pool scales by the value of `repeat` keyword. A random selection is made from each pool and tupled together as the final result.

See also [`more_itertools` docs](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) for more tools.