# Randomly sampling from multiple lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, random

I have some data currently stored in 3 lists, let's call them `a`, `b` and `c`. The lists all contain `n` elements. I would like to take a random sample of my data, say of size `sample_n`, to create some smaller dataset to play around with but I want to take the same random sample from each list. That is, I want to randomly select the same elements from each list. So if I randomly select element `i`, I would like to take element `i` from each list (`a[i]`, `b[i]` and `c[i]`). I do not want to generate 3 sets of random numbers so that the three lists' elements do not match. E.g.running [this random sampling](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-random-sample-function/) for each set separately is not what I want.

I would think all I need to do is generate a separate list of random numbers, `random_list`, that is of length `sample_n` and then do something like

```
for element in range(len(random_list)):
      sample_a[element] = a[random_list[element]]
      sample_b[element] = b[random_list[element]]
      sample_c[element] = c[random_list[element]]
```

However, I don't know how to generate a random number list! And also I was wondering if there was a more efficient method than what i was thinking of here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a shuffling of indices. First way:

```
import numpy as np
indices = list(range(20))
np.random.shuffle(indices)
indices
[9, 13, 0, 19, 17, 10, 14, 5, 7, 18, 8, 3, 16, 4, 15, 11, 12, 6, 1, 2]
```

Second way:

```
import random
indices = list(range(20))
random.shuffle(indices)
indices
[5, 3, 11, 7, 19, 12, 0, 13, 2, 4, 10, 18, 1, 16, 17, 14, 8, 6, 9, 15]
```

Or, in case indices can repeat:

```
np.random.randint(1,5, size=20)
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3])
```

Efficiency. It's faster to store `sample_a`, `sample_b`, `sample_c` in 2D array:

```
X = np.array([['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'], ['g','h','i'], ['j','k','l'], ['m','n','o'], ['p', 'q','r'], ['s', 't', 'u']])
idx = np.random.randint(0, len(X), size=7)
```

and then access its columns using `X[idx,0]`, `X[idx,1]`, `X[idx,2]`

Comment: Thank you! I think the third option is what i am going to go for. My code is now:
  
`sample_n = 1000`  
`data = np.column_stack((a, b, c))`  
`idx = np.random.randint(0, len(a), size = sample_n)`  
`idx = np.reshape(idx, (sample_size, 1))` #Force 1D vector  

Final dumb question (on this topic at least). I am now struggling to copy this sample_data into a new array. I have tried:
`for element in range(len(idx)):`  
`sample_data[idx[element], :] = data[idx[element], :]`  

But get the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple". Any ideas?

Sorry for the formatting!

Comment: reshape is unnecessary. You could just use `sample_data[idx,:]=data[idx,:]`

Comment: Thank you @mathfux, this is really good to know as my Python coding is currently very inelegant. I am still getting an error but I believe I ran into this same error about a week ago (for some reason it's not calling the `idx` elements as integer values) so hopefully I can learn from my past mistakes and fix this up!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, having searched earlier and not found anything I have just now immediately found this:

[Random sample of paired lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576914/random-sample-of-paired-lists-in-python)

Comment: note that in numpy, instead of `zip` you should probably go for `np.column_stack` or something similar

Comment: Thank you Adam. I will look into this too. I have come across it but am slightly intimidated by using `zip`. It seems quite a powerful command.